# MkParseDisplayName returns invalid syntax

Tags: mfc, com, atl

I'm struggling with something that should be simple, I want to create a moniker with a specific display name (e.g. "MyApplicationMnk")

I need this moniker to bind it to an EXE application registered in the Windows registry as `LOCAL SERVER` type to register it in the Running Object Table (aka. ROT)

the COM function [`MkParseDisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objbase/nf-objbase-mkparsedisplayname) returns `invalid syntax` error, the only [source](https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/21/) I found that mentioned a solution to this issue doesn't work with me.

The code is as simple as the following

```cpp
IMoniker* appmnk;
HRESULT hr;
CComPtr<IBindCtx> bct;
DWORD wctx = 0;
ULONG ulng = 0L;
CreateBindCtx(wctx, &bct);
OLECHAR dspnm = (wchar_t)"MyApplicationMnk";
LPCOLESTR dspnmptr = &dspnm;
hr = MkParseDisplayName(bct, dspnmptr, &ulng, &appmnk); // returns invalid syntax
.
.
//some code
.
.
appmnk->Release();
```

I've tried to insert the value directly like this

`hr = MkParseDisplayName(bct, OLESTR("MyApplicationMnk"), &ulng, &appmnk);`

and with the above-mentioned proposed solution like this

`hr = MkParseDisplayName(bct, (wchar_t *)(_bstr_t)(char *)"MyApplicationMnk", &ulng, &appmnk);`

I don't know what's wrong!, all the supplied types match what's said in the documentation.

Any help will be definitely appreciated.

Comment: You can't cast a char* into a wchar_t like you do, you can't use BSTR either. You should try with the L unicode prefix, for example try `MkParseDisplayName(bct, L"c:\\temp\\whataver.txt", &eaten, &mk)` on an existing file on your disk, it should get you back a valid IMoniker (a file moniker).

Comment: I've supplied the path for the exe application in light of what you've said,the good news is that it works and a moniker is already created (hr = S_OK), however, when this moniker is passed to `BindToObject` function, `BindToObject` returns `Bad extension for file`.

The bad news is when supplying any other string (for example L"MyApplicationMnk"), the same `invalid error` arises.

@SimonMourier

Comment: Also, for example `L"clsid:10000013-0000-0000-0000-0000000000001"`, `L"ProgID:MyApp.Application"` both fail, and `MkParseDisplayName` throws the usual `invalid syntax`!

Comment: L"clsid:10000013-0000-0000-0000-0000000000001" works fine for me.

Comment: `L"clsid:10000013-0000-0000-0000-0000000000001:"`, this is what did work, found it mentioned in the Essential COM book. A class moniker is created and I can find the application running as a background process, but `BindToObject` returns `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND) : The specified module could not be found. ` though I've loaded the correspondent Type Library with `LoadTypeLibEx` before creating the moniker.

Comment: ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND is more a deployment issue (a dll cannot be found). Try Process Monitor tool from sysinternals (you can filter by various things including process name) and trace what DLLs the system is probing.